# How can I remove 1 element in xml based on matched attribute and value?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to remove 1 element in xml based on matched attribute and value.
Here my XML file:

```
<Setup>
  <Include Type="Product">
    <Value uomid="8078">468908</Value>
    <Value uomid="8078">468922</Value>
  </Include>
</Setup>
```

Here My code:

```
XmlNodeList nodesMultipleUoM_delete = node.SelectNodes("//Value[@uomid='" + multipleUOM + "']");

if (nodesMultipleUoM_delete != null && nodesMultipleUoM_delete.Count > 0)
{
  for (int i = nodesMultipleUoM.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if (nodesMultipleUoM_delete[i].Attributes["uomid"].Value == multipleUOM.ToString())
    {
      nodesMultipleUoM_delete[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is this c#? add a c# tag then

Comment: Does your code work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yeah, it worked, but i got wrong result.

Comment: @TuấnTăng And that wrong result would be.....?

Comment: Code delete all <Value> now.
ex: So, i just set 2 parameter: 1 is 468908 that is node with attribute is uomid:8078 . And this <Value uomid="8078">468908</Value> will be deleted

Comment: Of course, all `Value` nodes have the same `uomid` value.

Comment: but it can discern by using this code 468908 or 468922

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your code are you checking whether the node value has the value you're looking for.

Try this:

```
List<XmlNode> toDelete = new List<XmlNode>();

foreach (XmlNode value in node.SelectNodes("//Value[@uomid]"))
{
    if (value.Attributes["uomid"].Value == multipleUOM.ToString() &&
        value.InnerText == valueToMatch.ToString())
    {
        toDelete.Add(value);
    }
}
foreach (XmlNode value in toDelete)
{
    value.ParentNode.RemoveChild(value);
}
```